# Why is default ScheduledItem StartDate a 'weird' value?

Tags: publishing, date-time, schedule, development

If you create a new ScheduledItem object and look at the StartDate - it's 1/1/1990 - why? This has just caught me out when trying to evaluate whether the dates have been set or whether they're, what I was guessing would be, MinDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if scheduling is activated on a SharePoint list, while adding a new item into the list, there are 2 options in the scheduled start date. Its either a "Scheduled Date" or "Immediately".

If a new list item is created to schedule immediately, these items would have a start date that is prior to the current date and internally SharePoint keeps this as "1/1/1990" to make it before the current date and to get it approved it in the next cycle asap. A similar explanation is given in the [msdn article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.scheduleditem.startdate.aspx) which you can go through.

Comment: Thanks Deepu - I understand the way scheduling works and how the date must be previous to the current date for the immediacy of publishing, but I don't get why it's 1990. MinDate would've done!? My reason for asking comes from the worry that it's not an actual hard-coded value SharePoint comes with but in fact calculated in some way - in which case I'd need to know about it for what I'm developing. Thanks again, +1.

Comment: There is a similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925626/sharepoint-date-and-time-field-limitation which says that if you try to insert the value 1/1/1800 in a Sharepoint Date and Time field manually (using Sharepoint forms) you receive this error:

"You must specify a valid date within the range of 1/1/1900 and 12/31/8900."

Therefore, SharePoint only accepts value between 1/1/1900 and 12/31/8900. That means, this could be some kind of a min date for SharePoint. :)